# Switch DB in Codeigniter Mongo class

Tags: php, codeigniter, mongodb

I am using codeigniter mongo class. I store the config information like mongohost, mongodb name etc in config/mongo.php in codeigniter. However, I would like to switch the db name in some places in my code, without having to re-write the config/mongo.php each time. Is there a switch db function or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

[You can set another in the config aside from your default one](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html):

```
// your code
$this->load->database('test');

// config
$db['test']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['test']['username'] = "root";
$db['test']['password'] = "";
$db['test']['database'] = "database_name";
$db['test']['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$db['test']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['test']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['test']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['test']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['test']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['test']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['test']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$db['test']['swap_pre'] = "";
$db['test']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['test']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->mongo->switch_db("data base name");
```

This should successfully switch the database.